# WinRT Component which references an x86 PCL: solve "mismatch between processor architecture"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

As a disclaimer, both the consumer of my WinRT component and the third-party library my WinRT Component will consume, cannot change their architecture and thus, resourcing to Stackoverflow with this predicament.

I have got to create a AnyCPU WinRT component which will be consumed by an AnyCPU project. However, my component requires a third-party library that targets x86. This prompts the "There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture, "x86", of the implementation file".

Looking at answers here and elsewhere, I tried to add the following to my WinRT Component project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
  None
 </ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To no avail. Am I missing something?

Comment: Targeting AnyCPU when you **know** that it can only ever run on x86 is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10/VS 2015, WinRT components cannot be built as AnyCPU. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx).

The C# code that you can write will be compiled to native code when your application will packaged.

On Windows 8, it was possible but if you have a dependency on a x86 only assembly then you should probably target only x86 instead of AnyCPU to be sure that everything will work as you expect.